# ExactTarget "Index was outside the bounds of the array" Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, landing-page

We've had a page running for a year now. It suddenly stopped working.  It processes appointment confirmations or cancellations.

The error I am receiving is this:

> An unexpected error has occurred! Error Message:  Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array.   Description:   An unexpected error occurred
>   during the execution of the page.   line 0, column 0 Exception Info:
>
> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DecryptSymmetric
>   function call.  See inner exception for details.
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:  Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array. Source:  mscorlib

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You should give ET support a call in this instance.  They have good tools that allows them to see what's going on that the rest of us don't have access to.